# Code format via short key and menu in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have java project in `Intellij` under `Windows`. Trying to format code by using Ctrl+Alt+L combination, but this does nothing. In case I go to menu `Code->Reformat Code` code formats perfectly. Why shortcut not works?

UPD

Key bindings:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check that your keyboard shortcuts are configured. To do this, press **Ctrl+Alt+S**, navigate to ***Keymap***, open up ***Main menu*** drop down, open ***Code*** folder and check that ***Reformat Code*** has a key combination set. You can also find *Reformat Code* via the search bar.

Comment: Looks like I have key combination setup, but it not works. More details in question body UPD

Comment: @vico try change the keybinding and then set it back?

Comment: I can set `ctrl+L` , but when I press `Alt` together nothing is set. Looks like pressing Alt makes ignore all rest key combinations